# Is there value in propTyping repeated required properties at every level of nested components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes, react-component

Say one component always calls another, but adds some properties, do you propType for required properties in this component even if they are checked in the component it calls? Or only at the higher level?

Simple Example:

```js
const Input = props => {
    let finalProps = {
        ...props,
        ...{onChange: (e) => props.onChange(props.id, e.target.value)}
    };
    return <input {...finalProps}/>
};

Input.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    tag: PropTypes.string
};
Input.defaultProps = {
    value: ''
};

const Checkbox = props => <Input {...props} type="checkbox"/>;

Checkbox.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

In this example, would you propType "Checkbox" as well as "Input" or just for "Input"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of looking at it is, that if you use some props in a component, you have to `propType` it and define relevant `defaultProps`. But if you are not using any of the props, and you are just passing them down without even accessing them, i would not use `propTypes` or `defaultProps`.

In your case `<Checkbox/>` does not use any of the props passed to it, but just passes them down to `<Input/>` component. Hence you don't need to `propType`, `id` or `onChange` in `<Checkbox/>`, but in `<Input/>` you are using `onChange` and since you are rendering a `<input/>` tag, there are props you should supply to it, so you need to check for `propTypes`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on all components which use the "Input" component. If all those higher-level components need to use the "type" prop, and I assume that they do, then I would put that property in the "Input" component, since it always appears and is always used.

Even if you have the situation when there are, for instance, 5 components which use the "Input" component, and 2 of those components work with a specific, but the same prop, I would put that prop, but without the "isRequired" attribute.